# Counting the number of characters from a text file

Tags: java, string

I currently have the following code:

```
public class Count {

    public static void countChar() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scannerFile = null;

        try {
            scannerFile = new Scanner(new File("file"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }

        int starNumber = 0; // number of *'s

        while (scannerFile.hasNext()) {
            String character = scannerFile.next();
            int index =0;
            char star = '*';
            while(index<character.length()) {

                if(character.charAt(index)==star){
                    starNumber++;
                }
                index++;
            }
            System.out.println(starNumber);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to find out how many times a * occurs in a textfile. For example given a text file containing
 Hi * My * name *

the method should return with 3

Currently what happens is with the above example the method would return:

0
1
1
2
2
3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the question?  what does not work as expected?

Comment: Does the code you have not work at the moment..?  If so, where does it fail?  What is your exact question?  And is this homework?

Comment: What's the current problem? Also, is this homework? If so there is a `homework` tag that should be added to the question.

Comment: This sounds like homework and Google'ing "java count character occurrences in text file" turned up a lot of results.

Comment: This is not homework, and I've tried googling it but with not much help specific to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in your method works fine, except that you print the count per line:

```
    while (scannerFile.hasNext()) {
        String character = scannerFile.next();
        int index =0;
        char star = '*';
        while(index<character.length()) {

            if(character.charAt(index)==star){
                starNumber++;
            }
            index++;
        }
        /* PRINTS the result for each line!!! */
        System.out.println(starNumber);
    }
```

Comment: Haha, that's the correct answer? I didn't think it would be *that* obvious :)

Comment: @Lukas: Could not believe it either - sometimes it's too easy :-)

Comment: Good job, @home. None of the rest of us could see the forest for the trees.  We all jumped in a rewrote his code without even looking at it first.  +1 for you.

Comment: @Paul, do you think this is some sort of test? :)

Comment: @Lukas, yes, and we all failed.  Now vote up home's answer like a good student.

Answer (score 3):

Use Apache commons-io to read the file into a String

```
String org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(File file);
```

And then, use Apache commons-lang to count the matches of `*`:

```
int org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.countMatches(String str, String sub)
```

Result:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(FileUtils.readFileToString(file), "*");
```

- http://commons.apache.org/io/
- http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: I expect that program using this code will run out of memory when file size exceeds `-Xmx` setting.

Comment: If you count the asterisks in the Koran, the Bible AND the Communist Manifest, then, yes ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
int countStars(String fileName) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    char[] cbuf = new char[1];
    int n = 0;

    while(fileReader.read(cbuf)) {
        if(cbuf[0] == '*') {
            n++;
        }
    }
    fileReader.close();
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should explain why for the benefit of the person asking, and answering, the question.  It's not efficient but it should work.

Comment: I think someone's just downvoting for kicks and giggles. I got downvoted too

Comment: IMHO nobody has asked for efficiency. Additionally, especially with newbie questions, I tend to give the most simple answer that uses as few library methods as possible to focus on basics.

Comment: @Lukas, I didn't like your solution but I didn't downvote you for it.  Whether I like something or not isn't the criteria for that :)

Comment: @Lukas: head -> desk (simplicity: I see a little hidden for loop) lol

Comment: @marc: No, better: head -> next bar and get a beer ;-) cu

Comment: @Paul: You will like it eventually, when you re-wrote your hand-crafted loop 500k times.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to the Java libraries at this point, then use other libraries (such as the commons libraries) as you become more familiar with the core Java API.  This is off the top of my head, might need to be tweaked to run.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String s = br.readLine();
while (s != null)
{
  sb.append(s);
  s = br.readLine();
}
br.close(); // this closes the underlying reader so no need for fr.close()

String fileAsStr = sb.toString();
int count = 0;
int idx = fileAsStr('*')
while (idx > -1)
{
  count++;
  idx = fileAsStr('*', idx+1);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something, like `fileAsStr.indexOf("*")`, when you write `fileAsString('*')` ?